# Подскажите пожалуйста документацию Telegram PAY

Tags: qiwi

Пишу бота по продаже, и не могу прикрутить оплату, помогите с этим вопросом, необходимо прикрутить qiwi.

Answer (score 0):

Советую воспользоваться ботом
[@ShopBot](https://telegram.im/@shopbot).

Исчерпывающая статья, там написано всё, что нужно знать: https://tgram.ru/blog/payments-bots/